# JQuery get value from dynamically created href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamical hyperlink generated via `jQuery`.  And I don't know how to get value of this element:

```
<a href="?t-action=' + data[i].pk_id + '" class="transfer">'+ '\ <img src="../images/like.png"...
```

But if i'm using `alert($(this).attr('href'));` The output is `?t-action=12345`
Is it posible to get only `12345`?

Comment: you can use split then get second data like `$(this).attr('href').split('=')[1]` assuming the value is always like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an attribute to `a` tag. In this case I use `data-`.

like this :

```
<a href="?t-action=' + data[i].pk_id + '" data-number="+data[i].pk_id+" class="transfer">
```

Then you can get than value by

```
$(this).data('number');
```

You can change the tag `data-number` to something else you prefer. Then update string inside `.data()` to be the same.

If you use `data-foo` in your jquery have to be `$(this).data('foo');`.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you to use data attributes.

```
<a href="?t-action=' + data[i].pk_id + '" data-pkid="data[i].pk_id" class="transfer">'+ '\ <img src="../images/like.png"...
```

Then, to output id use this:

```
alert($(this).data('pkid'));
```